Simple regulator circuit blowing transistor and Zener

I am making a simple 5V regulated output to power a fan. Vcc needs to vary from around 12V to 24V. the zener is 5.6V and is rated to 0.5W. the BJT is a 2N2222
When the load is not connected, I can feed 24V, the output stays at 5V no problem,
When the fan is connected total current is around 150mA, and as I increase voltage, the fan gets proper 5V until Vin gets close to 20V, then both the transistor and the Zener die and the fan suddenly spins as if it was getting 20V.
I am puzzled as to why this is happening,
the Zener resistor is 3,2k to limit current on the Zener, as I understand it Iz = Vin-Vout / Rs = 24-5 / 3.2k = 6mA, which is much less than the power rating of the Zener I=p/v = 0.5/5 = 100mA.
Also the current is around 150mA which is less that the max current of the 2N2222.
Collector-base voltage is also less than what the spec sheet of the 2N2222 Vcbo=75V.
What am I missing? My only conclusion is the 2N2222 is failing and taking the Zener with it. (I tested both after failure with DMM and both are indeed dead.)
I did two tries and burned 2 transistors and 2 diodes. The circuit is also correct since it works up to around 20V Vcc.
Thanks for the help

Hint: what’s the power dissipation when dropping 19 V at 150 mA?


What am i missing?

Heat.  Let me re-phrase that:  H.E.A.T.
In your circuit, the power the transistor is dissipating the voltage across it times the current through it.  With a 12 V input and a 5 V fan,
Power = (Vin - Vfan) x Ifan  ==
7 x 0.15 = 1.05 W.
This is around 10x what the transistor is rated for.  At Vin = 20 V, the power dissipation is 2.25 W.  Without a heatsink, this would cause a TO-3 packaged part to get too hot to touch, and many TO-220 packaged devices would fail.  A TO-18 or TO-92 part is doomed.
There are small, clip-on heatsinks for the TO-18 and TO-92 packages, but even with them attached the transistor will fail at the higher voltages.  It will just take longer.
According to a May, 2015 datasheet from ST (which of course I can no longer find online), the safe operating area plots for a metal TO-18 version with no heatsink and 7 V across it indicate a max collector current of less than 50 mA.  Higher voltages and currents are not allowed.


When the input voltage is 24 V, the 2N2222 will have to drop 19 V. At a fan current of 125 mA that means the 2N2222 will dissipate 19 * 0.125 = 2.375 W.
Looking at a sample of datasheets in TO-18 Metal Can Package or TO−92 plastic package 2.375 W exceeds the absolute maximum Power Dissipation and therefore will destroy the 2N2222.
